# How to handle removal of a related group of WPF UI Elements

Tags: wpf, listbox, stackpanel, gridsplitter

I'm interested in what is the best way to implement the removal of related set of UI elements.

This is what I'm working on: I have a Grid embedded within a verticle Scrollviewer.  The user can add multiple Listboxes to this Grid during runtime via a button click.  Each ListBox, when added, will also result in the addition of the correct number of Grid Rowdefinitions and a Gridsplitter to allow the resizing of each Listbox.  This parts works fine.

The trick is this -- the user also has the option of closing a Listbox.  When they do this, I will need to remove the corresponding Rowdefinitions and Gridsplitter that "belongs" to the closing Listbox.

Via iteration through Grid.Children and Grid.Rowdefinitions, I could somewhat easily figure out which Rowdefinitions and Gridsplitters to remove. But I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this.  Perhaps by grouping these elements together in a collection and simply removing this collection in one fell swoop?  No idea how to do this, though.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an obvious or simple way to associate them within the visual/logical tree, but you could certainly use an associative array (`Dictionary<T, U>`) that's keyed off of the element you're removing with the contents as the other items that need to be removed.

I think this is essentially what you described.

Anything more clever wouldn't be worth the additional complexity, I think, unless you had a specific need for it.  :)

Comment: For the lack of any other suggestions, I decided to use the .Tag property of other controls to store the HashCode of the ListBox these elements belong to.  I then iterate through the Grid collection of Children elements and RowDefinitions removing ones that match the closing Listbox's HashCode.